# Please help explain the method for finding the Euler Lagrange equations; I need help answering question 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Can someone help me with question 1, I'm struggling to find the EL equations, I don't understand if when I differentiate wrt $x$, if I have to differentiate $y$ because it is a function of $x$.

Comment: Write what you have and what you are trying to differentiate with respect to $x$. There are total derivatives with respect to $x$ and partial derivatives with respect to $y$ and $y'$.

Comment: hello, i have attached a picture but the integrand i have is f = x y(x) e^(2y'(x)),

Comment: I have been asked to show that the EL equations are y'' = (1-2y')/4y - 1/2x, my problem is when it comes to doing d/dx(df/dy'), i cant wrap my head around the differential

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} = 2xye^{2y'}$. That is partial. Now when doing the $x$ derivative it is total, so you do differentiate the $y$ and $y'$ which are functions of $x$. That is how you get the $y''$ you are supposed to end up with.